# How to prevent proxy URLs in link field from being encoded?

Tags: uri

Others appear to have similar issues to Drupal 8/9 encoding URLs in the link field though I see no solutions.

We're a library site and have many links for our patrons to external database websites that we link to with proxy URLs such as:

https://somewebsite.com/login?auth=password&url=https://link.gale.com/apps/doc/K1606004825/BIC?u=schools&sid=BIC&xid=2aefeae4

However, Drupal encodes the URL after the second https so it looks like:

https://somewebsite.com/login?auth=password&url=https%3A//link.gale.com/apps/doc/K1606004825/BIC%3Fu%3Dschools&sid=BIC&xid=2aefeae4

which returns an error.

Is there a way to turn off this function or disable URL encoding for the link field?

Comment: The first URL in your question is invalid (the second is fine) - you’re probably going to have a fight on your hands to get Drupal to output invalid URLs through the API

Answer (score 0):

I work for Denver Public Library and we ran into the same issue when we tried to post Ebsco permalinks on a Drupal 8 site.

As a workaround we are able to pass the URLs through a URL shortener and post that shortened URL.

A colleague of mine also remembered that they used to have to change permalinks before posting back on D6. They demonstrated that if you change a link from

https://ezproxy.yourlibrary.org/login?url=https://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&db=aph&AN=100123456&scope=site

to:

https://search.ebscohost.com.ezproxy.yourlibrary.org/login.aspx?direct=true&db=aph&AN=100123456&scope=site

the second link would work with a D8 and above URL field while the first would encounter the encoding issue.

I have shared this information with Ebsco and am creating a ticket for ProQuest. However, if nothing changes with the way they create their permalinks the URL shortener workaround has been effective for us.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at their admin and see if that works for us.

Comment: We are running into a similar issue with Tableau links, which have a colon in URLs with active filters, which doesn't follow the URL spec... We had to use the same solution, using link a shortener.

Answer (score 0):

In EBSCOadmin, there is a feature to create a proxy mask for Permalinks.

See the FAQ on EBSCO Connect site.
https://connect.ebsco.com/s/article/How-do-I-add-a-Proxy-Server-in-EBSCOadmin-and-embed-it-in-my-EBSCOhost-URL?language=en_US

The proxy mask should be like the following:
https://{targetURLDomain}.ezproxy.yourlibrary.org/{targetURLRemainder}

The above proxy mask would construct a URL like the below, which would work from Drupal.
https://search.ebscohost.com.ezproxy.yourlibrary.org/login.aspx?direct=true&db=aph&AN=100123456&scope=site

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah we'd already considered that though we have one site with over 1000 EBSCO permalinks so we were hoping for a programmatic workaround.